# Как вывести текущий id записи в mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

Создаю todo list на php mysql. Хочу сделать код который удаляет текущий запись через id.
Но вот не могу получить id текущего запися.

**Вот программный код:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Список дел</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Список дел</h1>
        <form action="add.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
            <input type="text" name="task" id="task" placeholder="Нужно сделать..." class="form-control">
            <input type="submit" name="sendTask" class="btn btn-primary" value="Отправить">
        </form>
        <form action="./del.php" method="post" class="taskCont">
            <?php
            $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "to-do");
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `tasks`";
            if ($res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                foreach ($res as $row) {
                    echo "<div class='task'>$row[task] <input type='submit' value='X' class='btn btn-danger'></div>";
                }
            }
            ?>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Это mysql код:**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: " не могу получить" --- не описывает проблему.  как минимум в ключите отображение ошибок и попробуйте воспользоваться отладкой кода, чтобы понять что где не так

Comment: Как обычно узнать id текущей строки в php

Comment: mysqli_query  - лишь исполняет запрос, для извлечения данных используют методы типа fetch_   - например https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  или https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста, как использовать этот метод для извлечения id текущей строки

Comment: Посмотрите в доки пожалуйста

Comment: Аналогично `$row[task]` надо написать `$row[id]`?

Comment: Вы же сами их получаете, сами выводите... и когда выводите среди прочих данных у вас есть и id, который вы кладете ровно в то место, из которого вам потом нужно будет его прокинуть. В том числе и в `<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?=$row['id']?>'/>` или в ссылку `<a href="/items/<?=$row['id']?>/delete">delete</a>` или в атрибуты элемента.

Comment: Я понял!!! Нужно было просто отправить id через GET.